# Add similar product to product view page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to show related products in product view page after product details. 
I added the below code in

> app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

page

```
<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product.info.details" after="-" />
```

then cache is cleared.its move successfully sill not show product

Comment: You mean after product tabs or after add to cart, wishlist etc?

Comment: after product tabs

Comment: Can you check my updated answer?

Comment: yeah! its working

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code this will add your related products at the end of product info main(After short description):

```
<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product.info.main.wrapper"  after="-"/>
```

If you want the related products to show after the product tabs then use the below code:

```
<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="content"  after="product.info.details"/>
```

OR

```
<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="content"  after="-"/>
```